# SOAP API in Play Framework Scala

Tags: scala, soap, playframework

Is there any complete step-by-step guide or material available on how to use `SOAP API` in `Play Framework` with `Scala`?
I have seen people post about `scalaxb` but couldn't find any guide on how exactly to use it. 
Any recommendation/link/repositroy will be helpful.

**P.S: I cannot use `REST API` because it's client's requirement to use `SOAP` and it CANNOT be changed. I have `WSDL` of the service I am supposed to interact with.**

Comment: Honest advice - Don't use play for this.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh thanks for your advice, you're absolutely right but I don't have any other option and have to do it this way.

Comment: Did you find the docs for the Play SOAP - http://downloads.typesafe.com/rp/play-soap/Home.html We have to integrate with SAP over SOAP where I work so we use this.

Comment: @Nio I think the OP wants to build SOAP api and not consume it.

Comment: @Sarvesh OP states that "I have WSDL of the service I am supposed to interact with."

Comment: Just because the OP has the WSDL does not necessarily mean consuming it.  Integrations often involve implementing an API defined in WSDL by a third party.  So they can call you via an agreed API.   Quite common in the financial and gambling domains at least.

Comment: And to answer the original question there are a variety of solutions I've looked at but never actually used to do exactly this including play-cxf.  Allows embedding of CXF framework into a Play app:
https://github.com/imindeu/play-cxf

NOTE - the default branch shown is for Play 2.1 but it has a branch for each major 2.x release.